# How to get lpar number of AS400 using php exec function

Tags: php, ibm-midrange

I need get info of serial number and lpar of AS400 (iSeries) by calling CL command from PHP exec function. This page: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzalc%2Fpase_commands.htm advise me get serial number by using sysval QSRLNBR, but I don't see any api for get lpar number. Please advise me how to get lpar number using php exec function (do not use ibm tookit), thanks

Answer (score 2):

With apologies @Buck, it can be a bit simpler than the previously posted reference to get LPAR info:

```
pgm

/*   For Retrieve System Status...                                  */

   dcl   &STS_DATA    *char    84
   dcl   &STS_LEN     *int            value( 84 )
   dcl   &STS_FORMAT  *char     8     value( 'SSTS0200' )
   dcl   &RESET_IND   *char    10     value( '*NO' )

   dcl   &ERRCODE     *char   116     value( x'00000074' )
   dcl   &ERRLEN      *dec  (   3 0 ) value( 0 ) /* +
                Will tell us how long any exception data +
                is... */


   call       ( QWCRSSTS )      ( +
                                  &STS_DATA +
                                  &STS_LEN +
                                  &STS_FORMAT +
                                  &RESET_IND +
                                  &ERRCODE +
                                )

/*   Test for an exception...                                       */
   chgvar      &ERRLEN        %bin( &ERRCODE 5 4 )

   if ( &ERRLEN *ne 0 )  do
      sndpgmmsg  msgid( CPF9898 ) msgf( QSYS/QCPFMSG ) +
                   msgdta( %sst(&ERRCODE 9 7) *bcat 'error +
                   exception' ) msgtype( *ESCAPE )
   enddo

   crtmsgf     QTEMP/tmpmsgf
   monmsg    ( CPF2112 )
   addmsgd     FMT0001  msgf(QTEMP/TMPMSGF)  +
                 msg('Total LPARs: &1 Current LPAR: &2') +
                 fmt((*BIN 4) (*BIN 4))
   monmsg    ( CPF2400 )

   sndpgmmsg   msgid( FMT0001 ) msgf( QTEMP/tmpmsgf ) +
                 msgdta( %sst( &STS_DATA 77 8 ) ) +
                 msgtype( *INFO )

   return

endpgm
```

There is only minimal error checking/handling in that, but also some extra code to create a formatted message at the end. The actual required code is pretty small.

Comment: BTW, if really needed, a *CMD (command) wrapper could be created. It's not clear how much iSeries help you have for your project or if you can modify the code to return values that you need.

Answer (score 1):

There's an API for that: `dlpar_get_info`

Chamara Withanachchi has a site where code examples can be found: Here is [dlpar_get_info](http://www.rpgiv.info/mambo/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=156&Itemid=76) in CL form.  You can write a CL program and call it the same way you are using RTVSYSVAL QSRLNBR.